# Windows keeps adding new devices every time I switch cables on my microphone

Tags: device-manager, input-device

I was trying out new cables for my microphone and every time Windows adds it as a new device. It creates another one saying Microphone (4- Movo...).

How can I reset the counter so it doesn't add another number every time I switch cables?

I think I managed to do it once a long time ago but I can't remember how.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td9yl.png)